# Machine boots into

Tags: boot-repair

During my update from 14.10 something failed and my machine only boots into Memtest. I booted from a boot-repair USB drive and performed the automatic repair, but the machine continues to boot into memtest. Grub also only shows memtest to boot.

Here's the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11064953/

I have a suspicion that I need to reinstall the kernel since I tried to clean /boot from older one and I might have overlooked something...
However, if I would have to do this, I would have no idea how to proceed from here.

EDIT
If this is a Kernel issue, the very thorough linked answers do not help unfortunately, probably because I have encrypted my volume. I failed to chroot /mnt with the error: failed to run command 'bin/bash/': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

If some error occured DURING the installation I strongly recommend you to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. This way you will avoid future headaches.